# How do you run an "input" stage only on master in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a stage in Jenkins declarative pipeline that I want to run conditionally when manually triggered, and only on the `master` branch.

```
stage('Deploy to prod') {
  when {
    branch 'master'
  }
  input {
    message "Deploy to prod?"
    ok "Deploy"
  }
  agent any
  steps {
    ..
  }
}
```

I'd like this stage to be skipped altogether for branches other than `master`, but what happens in practice is that it gets paused for all branches. Is there a way to get the behaviour I'm after?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the declarative pipeline doc for [`input`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input)

> The stage will pause after any options have been applied, and before entering the stage's agent or evaluating its when condition.

To make the pipeline work the way you specified, I would convert `input` to a (non-declarative style) step like this:

```
stage('Deploy to prod') {
  when {
    branch 'master'
  }
  agent any
  steps {
    input message: "Deploy to prod?", ok: "Deploy"
    ..
  }
}
```